# onClick jumping to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, navigation

I am coding a simple website with a JS side navbar. When I resize the window to develop at different widths I noticed that the page would jump to the top.
I then noticed that when I click the hamburger icon the page also jumps to the top.

I've looked into it and it appears to be the **onClick** that is the issue. I have tried to use **return false** but the issue is still the same.

I have used the code/tutorial provided on [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp). 
Thanks for any help

Here is my code

### HTML:

```
<nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav();return false;">&times;</a>

    <img class="sidenavbar-logo-img" src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo-NO.png'>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'sidenav-menu' ) ); ?>

<div class='sidebar-nav-info'>
    <p>Lower Trinity St,
    Birmingham,
    B9 4AG</p>
    <p>Facebook   Instagram</p>
    </div>

</nav>

  <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
  <span class="hamburger" onclick="openNav(); return false;">
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</span>
```

### CSS

```
      /* The navigation menu links */

      .sidenav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: 0;
      }

      .sidenav ul li {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .sidenav a {
          padding: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-weight: 700;
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #f1f1f1;
          display: block;
          transition: 0.3s;
      }

      /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
      .sidenav a:hover {
          color: #818181;
          text-decoration: none;
      }

      /* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
      .sidenav .closebtn {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 25px;
          font-size: 36px;
          margin-left: 50px;
      }

      /* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
      #main {
          transition: margin-left .5s;
          padding: 20px;
      }

      /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
      @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
          .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
          .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
      }

      .sidebar-nav-info {
        padding: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        color: #E2E2E2;
        font-size: 12px;
      }


/** HAMBURGER ICON **/
      span.hamburger {
        position: sticky;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 800;
        cursor: e-resize;
      }
```

### JS

```
<script>
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "300px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have suspected, this is caused by the `href=` in the `a` tag. By default, a tags navigate the page somewhere, so having either `href=#` or as yours is written, will just navigate to top of page.

The `return false` should do the trick, but it is likely not in the correct place. Try putting it inside the `closeNav` function, as the final statement. Else, you might need to create an event listener for a tags and just respond with the return false. You can also try `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` (but return false should work - it does more than preventDefault.

#### Update:

One thing that helps is to avoid using inline javascript (that is, where the js is on the tag itself: `onclick="closeNav();return false;"`). Instead, create an event listener and do your js there. [Here is a technical discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) regarding inline-javascript versus event listeners (the prevailing wisdom being that inline-javascript is more fraught and less desirable, particularly with respect to event bubbling, which is what you are dealing with here.) [Here is a more simple](https://gomakethings.com/listening-for-click-events-with-vanilla-javascript/) article.

So, switch to an event listener structure, like this (untested):

```js
var cbel = document.getElementsByClassname("closebtn");
cbel.addEventListener("click", closeNav, false);

var opel = document.getElementsByClassname("hamburger");
opel.addEventListener("click", openNav, false);



/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "300px";
    return false;
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    return false;
}
```

Final point: I would also recommend that you look into jQuery, because:

1) You are using bootstrap, which uses jQuery itself, so it is already loaded

2) It is much less typing

3) Most people (myself included) find it much simpler.  for example, the above code in jQuery would look like this:

```
$(function(){

    $('.closebtn').click(function(){
        $("#mySidenav").css('width', '300px');
        $("#main").css('margin-left', '300px');
    });

});//END document.ready
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to put the return false inside the close nav function but the side bar just doesn't open at all.